# Rails - CanCan HABTM association checks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have models set up as follows (self-association in contacts because information I wanted to store for resellers mirrored all fields in that table, seemed in keeping with DRY to use the already existing data structures):

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :reseller_id
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :reseller_clients, :class_name => "Contact", :foreign_key => "reseller_id"
  belongs_to :reseller, :class_name => "Contact"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr:accessible :name
  has_and_belongs_to_many :contacts
end
```

With cancan, I want to have a reseller login that is able to manage their own contact. The mapping between users and resellers is HABTM, so this can be achieved by doing `can :manage Contact, :users => {:id => user.id}` as below.

I also want the reseller login to be able to manage all Contact's which match the set described by managed_accounts in the following logic:

```
reseller_contacts = user.contacts
managed_accounts = []
reseller_contacts.each do |i|
  managed_accounts << i.reseller_clients
end
managed_accounts.flatten!
```

My current Ability class has:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    if user.role? :reseller
      # Allow resellers to manage their own Contact
      can :manage, Contact, :users => {:id => user.id} # This works correctly at present
      # Allow resellers to manage their client Contacts
      can :manage, Contact, :reseller => {:users => {:id => user.id}} #This doesn't work
    end
  end
end
```

The error I receive with it as it is, is as follows:

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.users' in 'where clause': SELECT `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` INNER JOIN `contacts` `resellers_contacts` ON `resellers_contacts`.`id` = `contacts`.`reseller_id` INNER JOIN `contacts_users` ON `contacts_users`.`contact_id` = `resellers_contacts`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `contacts_users`.`user_id` INNER JOIN `contacts_users` `users_contacts_join` ON `users_contacts_join`.`contact_id` = `contacts`.`id` INNER JOIN `users` `users_contacts` ON `users_contacts`.`id` = `users_contacts_join`.`user_id` WHERE ((`contacts`.`users` = '---\n:id: 6\n') OR (`users`.`id` = 6))
```

My understanding of cancan is that it checks on a per contact basis what is and isn't permitted. If I could do what I wanted in a block, it would appear as follows (Covers both the resellers own contact and all contacts which are clients of the reseller):

```
can :manage, Contact do |contact|
  user.contacts.exists?(contact.reseller_id) || user.contacts.exists?(contact.id)
end
```

I can't use a block for this however, as when trying to use `@contacts = Contact.accessible_by(current_ability)` in my index action on the controller, I get:

```
The accessible_by call cannot be used with a block 'can' definition. The SQL cannot be determined for :index Contact(id: integer, first_name: string, last_name: string, postal_addr_line_1: string, postal_addr_line_2: string, postal_addr_line_3: string, postal_addr_city: string, postal_addr_post_code: string, postal_addr_country: string, billing_addr_line_1: string, billing_addr_line_2: string, billing_addr_line_3: string, billing_addr_city: string, billing_addr_post_code: string, billing_addr_country: string, contact_email: string, company_name: string, phone_home: string, phone_work: string, phone_mobile: string, split_bills: boolean, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, reseller_id: integer)
```

### Edit:

ALMOST solved, now I just have a problem of combining abilities:

I changed the working part of my Ability model to read as:

```
reseller_contacts = user.contacts
managed_accounts = []
reseller_contacts.each do |i|
  i.reseller_clients.each do |rc|
    managed_accounts << rc.id
  end
end

can :manage, Contact, :id => managed_accounts
can :manage, Contact, :users => {:id => user.id}
can :create, Contact
```

Now the only problem is that the first `can :manage` line gets overwritten by the second one. I was under the impression that they should be additive, not replacing. More research required, but I think this question itself is fixed by the above. Now I need to work out how to make both `can :manage` lines apply.

Comment: Can you please rewrite "I want to have a reseller role that is able to see their own contact, as well as the contacts of all of their clients." differently, using the actual class and association names. For example there is no `:client` relation *(only `:reseller_clients` which is unused in the line you're having trouble with)*.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work, as for the second one of those 'can' lines, I need to get only the Contact's where they belong to a certain reseller, where that reseller has a HABTM association with the current_user. If I try to do can :manage, Contact, :reseller_clients => {???} I can't see anything I could put there which would help, as I then wouldn't be able to trace back to the HABTM association of the reseller Contact.

Comment: I am asking you to reword the quoted part of your Question; It's confusing.

Comment: In addition, having tried the following, I get that reseller_clients does not exist as a column:
`can :manage, Contact, :users => { :id => user.id }, :reseller_clients => :all` If I swap `:users` and `:reseller_clients`, I get the error that users does not exist as a column.

Comment: Question reworded. Did that help to clarify anything?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited 2015-03-26**

Having noticed that this question/answer was getting a bit of attention I thought I should point out a better method I've found since.

When creating has_one/has_many associations, rails creates `foreign_model_id`/`foreign_model_ids` methods respectively. These methods return an integer or array of integers respectively.

That means instead of the answer below, the entry in the `ability.rb` file can be simplified without having to use that ugly logic to create my own array of objects and iterate through them to:

`can :manage, Contact, id: (user.contact_ids + user.reseller_client_ids)`

**Previous answer kept for posterity**

Fixed by using this in my Ability.rb file:

```
# Manage all contacts associated to this reseller
reseller_contacts = user.contacts
managed_contacts = []
reseller_contacts.each do |i|
  i.reseller_clients.each do |rc|
    managed_contacts << rc.id
  end
  managed_contacts << i.id
end


can :manage, Contact, :id => managed_contacts
```

Deefour, thanks for your help along the way, don't think I'd have got there without your comments.

Comment: @bdx could I use `can :manage, Contant, user_ids: user.id` instead?

Comment: @gaussblurinc almost, but instead of `user_ids:` you'd use `user_id:`. The reason that wouldn't work for my situation is there were multiple ways a contact could be associated with a user.

Answer (score 1):

*I think you're still not wording your request as clearly as you could*

> ...the id of the reseller's own Contact

*The `:reseller` of a `Contact` is another `Contact`. There is no `:contact` attribute in `Contact`. Perhaps you're making things confusing by referring to "reseller role" and "reseller" when you should be referring to **user** (from the `CanCan` class) to avoid confusion with the `Contact` class' `:reseller` association)*.

I will assume

> reseller role to be able to manage all of the Contacts which have the reseller_id field set to the id of the reseller's own Contact.

to mean

> `user` can manage `Contact` `c` where `c.reseller_id` is the `user_id` of some Contact in `user.contacts`

Assuming this is an accurate interpretation:

```
can :manage, Contact do |c|
  user.contacts.where(:user_id => c.reseller_id)
end
```

Comment: I've just edited the question again to include a block at the bottom that would achieve what I want, and the error I get when I try it. Will try to reword my plain english requirements once more...